# Pytest not able to discover tests in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I have a simple project:

```
├── main.py
└── tests
    ├── main_test.py
```

main.py:

```
def a_function():
    print("test")
```

main_test.py:

```
from ..main import a_function

def test_a_function():
    a_function()
```

I want to make use of Visual Studio codes integration with python test libraries, specifically pytest. Following the creation of the project, i run the `Python: Discover Tests` command, which then creates the `.vscode` directory with the following `settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "."
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}
```

I then navigate to my `main_test.py` file, expecting to see the Run test/Debug test clickable commands that should be displayed above each test function. These are not shown. I then try and run the `Python: Discover Tests` command again, only to receive the following error:

```
Test discovery error, please check the configuration settings for the tests.
```

What am I missing? Any input is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the test output in the Output panel say after you run the `Discover tests` command? And one possibility is you didn't specify the full path to your tests, i.e. replace `.` with `directory/tests`.